# How to make the built-in analytic functions to use custom multiplication?

Tags: arithmetic

How to make the built-in functions like `Log`, `Sin`, `Exp` to work as power series but with custom multiplication operation, thus defining those functions on a space with custom multiplication?

Comment: Can you give an example of input and desired output?